# Does Galois group acts trivially on kernel of reduction?

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves, arithmetic-geometry

Let $L/K$ be a unramified quadratic extension of local fields.
Let $E/K$ be an elliptic curve over $K$.

We can consider reduction map $E(L)\to E(l)$ where $l$ is a residue field of $L$. Suppose characteristic of $k$ is odd.
Let $E^1(L)$ be kernel of reduction map.

I want to prove $Gal(L/K)$ acts trivially on $E^1(L)$.
How can I prove this ?

Suppose $\sigma \in Gal(L/K)$ acts on $P\in E^1(L)$.
$\tilde{\sigma(P)}=0$, thus $\sigma({P})\in E^1(L)$.Thus, $G$ acts on $E^1(L)$, but I cannot derive any infomation on this action.

Hints only is also appreciated.

Comment: The action is not trivial. The kernel of the reduction map is described by the maximal ideal of the ring of integers of $L$, endowed with a certain group structure. The Galois group does not act trivially on this maximal ideal. Eg if $K={\bf Q}_p$ then $E^1(L)$ is this maximal ideal ${\frak m}_{{\cal O}_L}$ with its ordinary group structure. The ideal ${\frak m}_{{\cal O}_L}$ corresponds to the expressions $\sum_{l>0}a_l p^l$, where the $a_l$ are Teichmüller lifts of elements of the residue field. The Galois group acts trivially on $p$ but not on the Teichmüller lifts.

Comment: unratified $\to$ unramified in your post

Comment: @Damian Rössler: Oh, you're right. I initially suspected that $H^1(\text{Gal}(L/K),E^1(L)) = 0 $, but it appears that's not the case. What are your thoughts on this cohomology? Can it be trivial even if the action isn't?

Comment: This is always trivial. The group $E^1(L)$ is isomorphic to ${\cal O}_L$ up to a finite quotient, which is in turn filtered with quotients isomorphic to the residue field $l$ of $L$ (see Silverman's book on elliptic curves, p. 174, p. 126 and p. 118). Now $H^1({\rm Gal}(L|K),{\cal O}_L)=0$ by a theorem of Noether (normal basis theorem for tamely ramified extensions) and $H^1({\rm Gal}(L|K),l)=0$ by a general theorem of Galois cohomology. The results follows.

Comment: Note that you will have triviality for any finite unramified extension of local fields.

Comment: @Damian Rössler:　Thank you very much. I understand the rest, but I'm not clear on the part $H^1(Gal(L/K), O_L)=0$. What exactly is the claim of the Noether's theorem you mentioned?　Is it different from Hilbert's Theorem 90?

Comment: See 1. in https://mathoverflow.net/questions/407345/cohomology-of-the-ring-of-integers-of-a-local-or-global-field

Comment: Hilbert’s theorem 90 is the fact that $H^1(Gal(L/K),K^*)=0$ (for any finite Galois extension of fields).

Comment: @Damian Rössler: Is your $L*$ instead of $K*$ in the statement of Hilvert 90 ? Have you ever seen the proof of normal basis theorem for tamely ramified extension in English ?

Comment: @Damian Rössler: I want to hear your thoughts on $H^1(Gal(L/K),l)=0$. In my opinion, by inflation-restriction sequence, it is enough to prove  $H^1(G_k,l)\cong WC(E/k)$ is trivial, but $WC(E/k)$ is trivial because every genus 1 curve has a rational point.

Comment: Yes, sorry $L^*$ not $K^*$ in H90. For a proof of Noether’s NBT in English, see https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/20251156.pdf

Comment: @Damian Rössler:Thank you very much. How about $H^1(Gal(L/K),l)=0$ ?Is there a simpler proof method than the one I mentioned in my previous comment?

Comment: This is a general result. If $L|K$ is any Galois extension of fields, then $H^1({\rm Gal}(L|K),L)=0.$ See the book by Cassels-Froehlich, 'Algebraic Number Theory', lemma 1, p. 124. This is also a consequence of an (easier) normal basis theorem: there is an element of $L$, whose Galois orbit forms a basis of $L$ over $K$.

Comment: ＠Damian Rössler
To prove $H^1(Gal(L/K),E_1(L))=0$, you used $E_1(L)\cong \pi O_L$, but group action of (Gal(L/K)$  on $E_1(L)$ and $\pi O_L$ may not be the same, so the group cohomology may differ. How do you justify this matter ?